# discord.py error handling for every command in a cog

Tags: python, error-handling, discord.py

I would like to add some error handling to my cog, as all the commands require an argument of a user. However, the only way I have found to do this would require each command to have its own error handle, which is very time consuming as I have 50+ commands all with this format.

If possible, I would like to be able to create an error handler, that only works for the commands in that one cog. How would I go about this?

Example commands:

```py
  @commands.command()
  async def poke(self, ctx, tag: Optional[discord.Member]=None, *args):
    self.poke = False
    await ctx.send(f"{tag.mention} Has been poked by {ctx.author.mention}")

  @commands.command()
  async def fight(self, ctx, tag: Optional[discord.Member]=None, *args):
    self.fight = False
    await ctx.send(f"{tag.mention} Has been fought by {ctx.author.mention}")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cog-specific error handling can be done by overriding [`cog_command_error`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Cog.cog_command_error) in the cog class:

```py
class Test(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def poke(self, ctx, tag: Optional[discord.Member] = None, *args):
        self.poke = False
        await ctx.send(f"{tag.mention} Has been poked by {ctx.author.mention}")

    @commands.command()
    async def fight(self, ctx, tag: Optional[discord.Member]=None, *args):
        self.fight = False
        await ctx.send(f"{tag.mention} Has been fought by {ctx.author.mention}")

    # Cog error handler
    async def cog_command_error(self, ctx, error):
        await ctx.send(f"An error occurred in the Test cog: {error}")
```